# What happens at Back-end when I abort an Ajax request at Front-end

Tags: java, ajax

I have a HTML page in which I have 2 buttons, *next* and *previous* (for switching between weeks), and every time a button is clicked I send an Ajax request at back-end (JAVA).

When the *next* or *previous* buttons are pressed, I abort the previous request and send a new one.

What I can't understand is, **what happens in the back-end when I abort a request at the front-end**? Because I send HTTP requests from the back-end to external endpoints (Microsoft Graph), and I need to abort these requests as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every request arrived at BE will be processed.

You will receive more than one response from back-end in this case. You can't abort request if it already arrived at back-end.

Comment: So i guess due to microsoft's multiple HTTP requests restrictions at Microsoft Graph I have to restrict Ajax calls from the front - end . Right?

Comment: If you have restriction I guess yes, but I don't know Microsoft Graph. 
In general is not useful call back-end multiple time uselessly.

Comment: Just think that every time previous or next button is clicked , i have to get some Calendar events from graph , for every week. So I have to call back - end . 
The other solution is to wait for 1 sec after a button is clicked and after that , if no other button is clicked to send the request at back-end . 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, I think you can wait while the single request are not performed (and then you have received the response from back-end).

In general you can add a boolean that enable user to click next/previous button based on a determinate behaviour. That behaviour could be "there are not request in pending" (is my personal suggestion, but you have multiple choice to solve this.)